# How to get Twitter data into KNIME for sentiment analysis

Tags: twitter, knime

Here is what I tried, with the following result:

[image: KNIME nodes]

```
ERROR Twitter Search       0:2        
Execute failed: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were 
missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access 
token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
message - Invalid or expired token.
code - 89
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the parts the error message mentions? Have you tried rerunning the connector? Do other apps work with your keys/secrets?

Answer (score 1):

Try regenerating the API keys and secrets. The Twitter API Connector node will "run" and show green lights even if the connection is not established. I have had this issue a number of times, going on the Twitter developer site and  generating new tokens, entering them in KNIME and running your flow again will fix the issue (hopefully).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8kCw.png)